# ¿Stack Overflow regala becas para asistir a sus eventos?

Tags: discusión, encuentros-locales

Vi que Stack Overflow realiza eventos, y es por ello que tengo la siguiente duda (No lo tomen a mal):

¿Stack Overflow regala becas para asistir a sus eventos?

Mi duda surgió porque una compañera fue becada para asistir a un evento de Latinity.

Con beca me refiero a pagar el viaje del becado para que logre asistir a tal evento

Comment: Como se explica en el posible duplicado que señala @fedorqui, hasta donde yo se, Stack overflow suele colaborar en los eventos que se organizan con un "catering", pero nunca he leido nada de becas...

Comment: ¿Sabes de algún evento que tenga costo?

Comment: @Rubén a que te refieres con costo?

Comment: @x-rw ¿a qué te refieres con beca? :)

Comment: @Rubén ya comprendo, con beca me refiero a pagar el viaje del becado para que logre asistir a tal evento.

Comment: @x-rw recién encontré [How can I get Stack Exchange to send me to a conference?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132282/289691)

Comment: @Rubén A que bien, es la respuesta que esperaba, todo muy claro, pero no esta en español.

Comment: @x-rw Considera solicitar que se reabra esta pregunta para que se pueda agregar la traducción como respuesta (no prometo hacer yo mismo la traducción)